# Scratch org creation fails Error parsing Address.settings

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

When I try to make a scratch org with the command:

`sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername DEVHUB --wait 10 --durationdays 1 --definitionfile project-scratch-def.json`

I get the following error:
[image]

My `project-scratch-def.json` looks like:

```
  "orgName": "Impact",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "HealthCloudUser", "LightningScheduler", "StateAndCountryPicklist"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "passwordPolicies": {
        "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true,
      "enableAccountHistoryTracking": true,
      "showViewHierarchyLink": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true
    }
  }
}
```

I had no problem creating scratch orgs before. This error showed up out of nowhere and now it occurs everytime. The only case where I can get the scratch org creation to success is if I remove all the Features and Settings from my `project-scratch-def.json`, but I need those for my org to have the correct shape. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This has bitten me before. This issue appears to crop up when you add addressSettings to your project-scratch-def.json - the scratch fails to create and you then then subsequently remove addressSettings.

The only way I have found to resolve this is to delete the scratch folder in your temp directory prior to running `sfdx force:org:create`

I'm on a windows box and I located the scratch folder and the subsequent scratch.zip in the default temp dir

```
Users/YourUser/AppData/Local/Temp
```

After deleting from here it built as expected with no address settings.

Its worth noting you can set the temp directory using

```
SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR
```

Example:

```
SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=/users/myName/myDXProject/metadata
```

You can read about it more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm)